# How to beautify a json file without doing sytax check?

Tags: json

I want to beautify a json file and just for a clear looking and I just want to get an correct indent lines but the tools I googled all need to do syntax check and all would complain that it has illegal syntax like single quote or undefind property eth. Is there any tools that just doing beautyfy and no syntax checks now?

The test json below:

```
[{$group:{_id:{year:{$year:'$registerTime'},month:{$month:'$registerTime'},day:{$dayOfMonth:'$registerTime'}},sources:{$push:{platform:'$registerSource'}}}},{$group:{_id:{date:'$_id'}}}]
```

And I want to get the result like:

```
[
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: {
                $year: '$registerTime'
            },
            month: {
                $month: '$registerTime'
            },
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth: '$registerTime'
            }
        },
        sources: {
            $push: {
                platform: '$registerSource'
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: '$_id'
        }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: If it has illegal syntax, then it is not JSON.

Comment: Need to quote the keys. It might be legal JS, but it isn't legal JSON.

Comment: Yeah, It may not be a legal JSON. Is there any tools can do less strict check and just for clear looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here... plenty options to choose from 
[JS beautifier](https://beautifier.io/)

Comment: From your answer I know that `js-beautify` is really what I wanted.

Comment: That is right, in there you have many ways to implement the tool, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can tidy up your string by properly quoting things:

1. Replace single quotes with double quotes
2. Replace words with quoted words
3. Replace resulting duplicated double quotes with double quotes

Assuming `data` is your string:

```
import re, json
data1 = data.replace("'", '"')
data2 = re.sub(r'([\w$]+)', r'"\1"', data1)
data3 = data2.replace('""', '"')
legally_formatted = json.loads(data3)
# [{'$group': {'_id': {'year': {'$year': '$registerTime'}, 
# 'month': {'$month': '$registerTime'}, 
# 'day': {'$dayOfMonth': '$registerTime'}}, 
# 'sources': {'$push': {'platform': '$registerSource'}}}}, 
# {'$group': {'_id': {'date': '$_id'}}}]
```

Once you get legally formatted data, you can pretty print it anty way you want.